# SFDX Error in macOs Big Sur

Tags: salesforcedx, mac-os-x, sfdx-error

Getting this below error with macOs Big Sur. Any help.

```
sfdx --version
/usr/local/bin/sfdx: line 44: /usr/local/lib/sfdx/bin/node: Bad CPU type in executable
```

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling SFDX yet?

Comment: yes. It is a fresh installation.

Comment: Maybe upgrade software to latest. Current latest version is macOS Monterey (12.1)

Answer (score 15):

I'm going to assume you're on a newer Mac using the Apple M1 chip. There's already an [open issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1045) on the CLI github regarding this error.

It seems they're waiting for Nodejs to release a version that supports the M1 chip.

The workaround, for now, is to install [Rosetta](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211861) on your Mac. This

> enables a Mac with Apple silicon to use apps built for a mac with an
> Intel processor.

The below command will help you install it

`softwareupdate --install-rosetta`

Answer (score 4):

SFDX CLI ships with node 12 which does not support M1 chips.

Basically, you should just delete it and link a recent version of nodejs to its directory using the commands below (assuming you have nodejs installed by homebrew).

```
rm -f /usr/local/lib/sfdx/bin/node
link -s /opt/homebrew/bin/node /usr/local/lib/sfdx/bin/node
```